# Pilhas com vetores em C, está mostrando os elementos que já foram retirados

Tags: c, array, stack

Como faço para mostrar meu vetor sem os números que foram retirados? Pois quando eu mostro ele, mesmo eu retirando um número na função, ele ainda aparece lá dentro.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 10

int pilha[MAX];
int inicio,fim;

int pilhaCheia(){
    return (fim == MAX);    
}
int pilhaVazia(){
    return (inicio == fim);
}
void push(int x){
    if( !pilhaCheia() ){
        pilha[fim++] = x;
    }else{
    printf("Pilha cheia \n");   
    }
}
int pop(){
    int aux;
    if( !pilhaVazia() ){
        aux=pilha[fim];
        fim--;
        return aux;

        }else{
            printf("Pilha vazia \n");
        return -1;  
        }
    }


void exibe(int pilha[MAX]){
    int x;
    for( x=0; x < MAX; x++){
        printf("%d",pilha[x]);
    }
}

main(){

    inicio = 0;
    fim = 0;
    int escolha,valor;
    do{
    printf("\n1 EMPILHA:\n");
    printf("\n2 DESEMPILHA:\n");
    printf("\n3 Mostra:\n");
    printf("\n4 Sair:\n");
    scanf("%d",&escolha);
    int x;
    switch(escolha){
        case 1:
            printf("Escolha o valor:");
            scanf("%d",&valor);
            push(valor);
            break;
            case 2:
            printf("%d",pop());
            break;
            case 3:
            exibe(pilha);   
            break;
            default:
            break;
    }



    }while( escolha != 4);  

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só mudar a condição do seu `for` na função `exibe`:

```
for( x=0; x < fim; x++){
    printf("%d",pilha[x]);
}
```

Observe que aqui eu usei `fim` ao invés de `MAX`.

Comment: Vlw pela ajuda, fiquei um tempao pensando haha

Comment: @IgorVargas Se essa resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 